# Can HLint automatically do suggested edits?

Tags: haskell, refactoring, automated-refactoring, hlint

[HLint](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hlint) gives suggestion how one can improve source code. However, given the nature of the suggestions, I wonder whether it's possible to automatically apply those suggestions.

Is it possible to automatically apply suggestions proposed by `hlint`?

Comment: maybe the [HaRe project](https://github.com/RefactoringTools/HaRe) and [this repo](https://github.com/mpickering/apply-refact) are of interest to you

Comment: @willie: Why would code be necessary for this question? It's just about the usage of a programming related tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `--refactor` and have the `refactor` executable in your `$PATH`. See [hlint's README](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint#readme) for more information:

> #### Automatically Applying Hints
>
> By supplying the `--refactor` flag hlint can automatically apply most
>   suggestions. Instead of a list of hints, hlint will instead output the
>   refactored file on stdout. In order to do this, it is necessary to
>   have the `refactor` executable on you path. `refactor` is provided by
>   the [`apply-refact`](https://github.com/mpickering/apply-refact)
>   package, it uses the GHC API in order to transform source files given
>   a list of refactorings to apply. Hlint directly calls the executable
>   to apply the suggestions.

Note that hlint doesn't apply transformations recursively, so additional `--refactor` could be nec­es­sary. That being said, make sure to commit/save before you apply `hlint --refactor` and test your code afterwards, since the changes might break your code, especially if you use Rank2Types or `seq`.

Answer (score 0):

To complement Zeta's answer, I use some additional flags to perform the refactoring in place:

```
hlint  --refactor --refactor-options="--inplace" path/to/your/File.hs
```

Sometimes you only want to apply a certain kind of hint, which can be done by passing the `-o` flag, e.g.:

```
hlint  -o="Use fewer imports" --refactor --refactor-options="--inplace"
```

As far as I know, the suggested refactorings need to be done in a per-file basis.